# When to use a custom model manager?

Tags: django, django-models, django-managers

Right now i'm reading about custom managers that you can use to add additional logic when doing a CRUD action like Create. You make a custom manager class and then initialize the `objects` attribute of the table class with an instance of the custom manager class.

I've also read that you can also use the pre_save and post_save signals to add additional save logic to the save action. My question is: When should i use a custom manager class over signals and is the use of a custom manager slower then the default manager of the Model class?

Thank you

Comment: When you (nearly) always want to filter/annotate/...

Comment: what do you mean with filter/annotate?

Comment: You have a `Book` with a ForeignKey to an `Author`. You define the Book manager such that all queries com back annotated with `author_name` which is more efficient than referring to `author.name`.

Comment: @nigel222 can you give a code example of what your trying to say? thx

Comment: @FAM_Maurice OK see my answer

Answer (score 1):

OK, here's one I wrote earlier. I've cut out a lot of irrelevant stufff, hoping all the essentials remain.  You need to know there's a Foreign Key chain `PRSBlock` -> `PRS2` -> `Jobline` -> `Description`. Using this, all queries for `PRSBlock.objects.filter(...` will return `PRSBlock` objects with extra fields `membrane_t`, `substrate_t` and `material` from the `Description` found by following this chain. They're almost always needed in this context, unlike most of the other things along that chain. `select_related` would be serious overkill.

```
class PRSBlock_Manager(models.Manager):   

    def get_queryset(self):
        return super().get_queryset().annotate(
            membrane_t = F('PRS__jobline__description__mt'), 
            substrate_t= F('PRS__jobline__description__ft'),
            material   = F('PRS__jobline__description__material')
        )

class PRSblock( models.Model):

    # override the default manager
    objects=PRSBlock_Manager()  # annotate always with description parametrs relevant to block LUTs

    PRS = models.ForeignKey( PRS2, models.CASCADE, related_name='prs_blocks')
    # and lots of other fields that aren't relevant
```